How do I define the solution to an inequality?
I have this inequality $$|x-1|+ |x+2|>3$$
and I have found my first solution $S_1$ which is an intersection of $[1,+\infty]$ and $(1,+\infty]$ but I don't know if the intersection of these two sets will give a strictly closed set or an open/close set.
So, my question is whether my solution will be $[1,+\infty]$ or $(1,+\infty]$?
I really appreciate all the help on this question. I have understood the logic concerning this. Since $1$ does not satisfy the inequality, it will not be a part of the range of answers. Hence, making it an open set.

But $x=-20$ is a solution to the inequality, so your interval answers do not give all solutions.

@AdamRubinson they did say my 'first' solution, I assume they know that there is also a negative region which will be mirrored about 0

substiting in the value $x=1$ into the expression we get the value $3$, so we know $1$ cannot be within the set and so it must be an open/close set

The intersection of two equal sets? $+\infty$ is not a real number, so we usually use a parenthesis on the right in an interval including $+\infty.$ $(1,+\infty)$ or $[1,+\infty).$

@HenryLee So I just have to apply an example to see for sure. Okay, thanks

@AdamRubinson yes, I know that. My final solution is a union of this $S_1$ and another $S_2$. Thanks for pointing it out. If I didn't know already, it would have been really helpful

Well.  Is $x=1$ a solution?  Is $|(1)-1| + |(1) +3|> 3$?

$A\cap B = {x|x \in A$ AND $x\in B}$.  $A= [1,\infty) = {x| x \ge 1}$ and $B=(1,\infty)={x| x> 1}$.  So $[1,\infty)\cap (1,\infty)={x$ so that $x \ge 1$ AND $x> 1$ are both true$}$.  If $x < 1$ then none of theses are true.  If $x = 1$ then $x\ge 1$ is true but $x>1$ is NOT true. And if $x> 1$ then both are true.  So both are true IF AND ONLY IF $x > 1$.  So $[1,\infty)\cap (1,\infty)={x| x> 1} = (1, \infty)$>  Sorry to state the obvious and go overboard on the detail but if you know the definitions cold, this can and should be immediate and crystal clear.

As noticed in the comments, at $x=1$ we have
$$|x-1|+ |x+2|=|1-1|+|1+2|=3$$
therefore $x=1$ is not a solution and $S_1$ is the interval $(1,\infty)$.
Similarly we find that $S_2$ is $(-\infty,-2)$.

I will give an answer along the lines of copper.hat, but going into more detail of how one might arrive at his answer.

We make use of a definition of $\vert t\vert, $ which is:
$
\vert t \vert:=
\begin{cases}
 -t&\text{if}\, t<0\\
 t&\text{if}\, t\geq 0.\\
\end{cases}
$
An alternative but equivalent definition would be to put the "equals" part with $<,$ rather than $>.$

OP, your instinct when solving the inequality $\vert x-1\vert+\vert x+2\vert>3$ should be a proof by exhaustion, splitting into the following mutually exclusive, exhaustive cases:
Case $1:\ x<-2.$
Case $2:\ x=-2.$
Case $3:\ -2< x < 1.\quad [x> -2$ and $x<1.]$
Case $4:\ x=1.$
Case $5:\ x> 1.$
Let us start by dealing with Case $1:$ "$x<-2$ is true". Here, both $ x-1$ and $x+2$ are negative, which means that $\vert x-1 \vert = -(x-1)$ and $\vert x+2 \vert = -(x+2).$ The original equation $\vert x-1\vert+\vert x+2\vert>3$ is thus equivalent to: $ -(x-1) + -(x+2)>3,$ which implies $x<-2.$ We can see that, if $x<-2,$ then the original equation holds, although everything so far has been scratchwork, and I don't think we have actually "solved anything" clearly yet with a logical argument. We must "back-track" or make a logical argument somehow, starting with "under assumption that $x<-2$", and ending in "then the original equation holds". Here is one such argument, making use of our scratchwork:
If $x<-2,$ then $\left(\ -(x-1) + -(x+2)>3 \text{ and } \vert x-1\vert=-(x-1)\text{ and }\vert x+2\vert = -(x+2)\ \right),$ which implies $\vert x-1\vert + \vert x+2\vert > 3.$

OP - can you use similar reasoning to see what happens for cases $2-5,$ and logically prove what happens in each case?

Of course, once you have enough experience with these inequalities, if you feel confident enough and have checked the logic, you can use iff to make the proofs shorter.

Remember that $A \cap B$ is all elements that belong in both $A$ and $B$.
Is $1$ in both $(1,\infty]$ and $[1,\infty]$? Answer that, and you have your answer.

I would suggest plotting the left hand side first to guess the answer.
Let $f(x) = |x-1|+|x+2|$.
For $x \le -2$, $f(x) = 1-x -2-x = -2x-1$, and $-2x-1 > 3 $ iff $-x>2$ iff $x<-2$.
For $x \in [-2,1]$, $f(x) = 1-x+x+3 = 3$, so no element of $[-2,1]$ satisfies the inequality.
For $x > 1$, $f(x) = x-1+x+2 = 2x+1$, and $2x+1>3$ iff $x>1$.
Hence the solution is $(-\infty,-2) \cup (1, \infty)$.

Why the downvote? Something wrong?

Also my answer was downvoted, probably it's a troll.

A faster method is to recall that $|x-x_0|$ measures the distance of the point $x$ from the point $x_0$. So the set of solution of the inequality is given by the points such that $($distance from $1$, given by $|x-1|$ $)+ ($distance from $-2$, given by $|x+2|$ $)$ is bigger than $3$. Hence $x>1$ or $x<-2$.
